# How can I enable server certificate verification when connecting to a remote host, but not when connecting via localhost?

Tags: mariadb, ssl, tls-1.2

When I add `ssl-verify-server-cert` to a `[client-mariadb]` section in the configuration files, the client correctly verifies the server certificate when connecting to a remote MariaDB instance.

When attempting to login on the client itself via localhost, however, login fails with a TLS validation error:

```
mariadb -u root -v 
ERROR 2026 (HY000): TLS/SSL error: Validation of SSL server certificate failed
```

Removing `ssl-verify-server-cert` allows logging in from localhost normally.

How can I enable server certificate verification when connecting to a remote host, but not when connecting via localhost?

I presume the error is because `localhost` is not the domain in the certificate on the client machine. But I also feel that adding `localhost` as a Subject Alt Name is probably not a good idea.

Is there a solution or recommended practice for this?